# Jira Groovy Runner ask for user input

Tags: groovy, input, jira

I was wondering if there was a way to have the Jira Script Runner allow some sort of user input whether in the form of when entering the file location and then adding the input ie "C:/fakepath/myScript.groovy -my input"
Even better would have it create a input box.

I am asking because I want to create a script to create a bunch of jira issues base upon the user input.  I realize I could just create a string instead of the user input and then just edit the code each time I use it, but it would be much more efficient if I didn't have to do that. If groovy in jira can do such a thing that would be great.

I tried using the following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
print "Input:"
def userInput = br.readLine()
println "You entered: $userInput"
```

but it just constantly runs waiting for the user input, but nothing pop-ups where I could enter it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works

```
println "Input:"

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
def userInput = br.readLine()
println "You entered: $userInput"
```

My guess is your program is waiting for input, but it has not printed the message due to buffering.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just needed to add an `System.out.flush()` before the `br.readLine` to get it to go through.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.emoticode.net/groovy/console-input-read-in-groovy.html

```
System.in.withReader {
  println "Test: "
  carrier = it.readLine()
}
```